# Order date ascending

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Basicly i have a model BalanceUsers with expendes and earnings and a date column, what i want is query that table and order all the rows by date ascending, i need to do that soo i can search between a startDate and an endDate that i send from a form to get values restricted between this two dates, but nothing happened maybe i did something wrong.

**Here is what i did**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string startDate, string endDate)
    {
        DateTime data1 = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
        DateTime data2 = DateTime.Parse(endDate);

        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        decimal gastos = 0;
        decimal rendimentos = 0;

        var orderDates = db.BalanceUsers.Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId).OrderBy(d => d.data);  //this is what does the job 

        var lowestValue = orderDates.Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId).Min(d => d.valor);
        var BiggestDate = orderDates.Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId).First(d => d.valor == lowestValue);
        var dateBiggestDate = BiggestDate.data;

        var biggestValue = orderDates.Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId).Max(d => d.valor);
        var biggestDate2 = orderDates.Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId).First(d => d.valor == biggestValue);
        var biggestDateEarning = biggestDate2.data;
        foreach (var balance in orderDates.Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId))
        {
         if(balance.valor < 0)
            {
                expenses += balance.valor;
            }
         else
            {
                earnings += balance.valor;
            }
        }
 statistic model = new statistic()
        {
            utilizador = User.Identity.GetUserName(),
            gastos = gastos,
            rendimentos = rendimentos,
            maiorValorDespesa = lowestValue,
            dataMaiorDespesa = dataMaiorDespesa,
            dataMaiorRendimento = dataMaiorRendimento,
            maiorValorRendimento = biggestValue,
        };

        return View(modelo);
```

In my view i just display the data that i passed to my modelView, so i dont think the problem is on the view.

PS: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Is `data` the property which stores the DateTime value  in `BalanceUser`? Also i do not see code where you are doing the date filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For next time or if you want more help

1. It would really help if you did some translating of your code to English. I have no idea what the properties actually mean so I am going to take some guesses here based on what you have written.
2. It would also help if you provided your model for the object you are working with in your method.
3. Finally it would help if you described what it is you are trying to accomplish.

---

That said I looked at your code and it seems you can do everything in there with just 1 call. Also no where in your code do you actually make use of those dates that are passed in. Also why are you not passing them in as actual `DateTime` objects?

```
var highestLowestValors = db.BalanceUsers.Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId)
    .GroupBy(x => x.ApplicationUserId)
    .Select(x => new {
        biggestValor = x.Max(y => y.valor), 
        lowestValor = x.Min(y => y.valor),
        expenses = x.Where(y => y.valor < 0).Sum(y => y.valor),
        earnings = x.Where(y => y.valor > 0).Sum(y => y.valor),
    }).Single();
```

> i need to do that soo i can search between a startDate and an endDate

First Sql is a declaritive language. This means you do not need to order the data and then loop through it to get what you need. Instead declare that you only want data between those 2 dates. Lets say your date column for your table `BalanceUsers` is called `OccurredOn`, you would change the query like so.

```
DateTime startDateSearch, endDateSearch; // assign these values somewhere
var highestLowestValors = db.BalanceUsers.Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId && d.OccurredOn >= startDateSearch && d.OccurredOn <= endDateSearch)
    .GroupBy(x => x.ApplicationUserId)
    .Select(x => new {
        biggestValor = x.Max(y => y.valor), 
        lowestValor = x.Min(y => y.valor),
        expenses = x.Where(y => y.valor < 0).Sum(y => y.valor),
        earnings = x.Where(y => y.valor > 0).Sum(y => y.valor),
    }).Single();
```

Comment: good answer, and sorry for bad translation im kinda new on .Net mvc, can you explain me that OccuredOn cause it doesnt work here where did you get that?

Comment: @FilipeCosta - You mentioned you wanted to filter on a balance date but you never mentioned what your property was named. I took a guess (I mentioned that above) and just called it `OccurredOn`. You can change that to whatever your column is actually called.

Comment: sorry i got it, but just 1 thing how can you get the date related to the lowestvalue for example?

Comment: @FilipeCosta - add the following to the anonymous object as a new property: `lowestDate = x.Where(y=> y.valor == x.Min(z => z.valor)).Select(y => y.YourDate).First()`